# installing Mono 2.10+ in Ubuntu 8.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mono

Firstly I realise that 8.10 is an old unsopported release of Ubuntu but it is on an intranet and i cant update it... but I have 2 questions

1. I want to install mindtouch an open source wiki engine onto it but it needs mono 2.10.2+ to work so I'd like to know is it even possible to install that version of mono on Ubuntu 8.10 server edition
2. If it is possible then can anyone tell me how. I've been stuck on it for a few days unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution IMO is to compile and install it from sources, there are not many dependencies and you should be able to satisfy them easily. So, after downloading and unpacking [latest stable sources](http://download.mono-project.com/sources/mono/mono-2.10.8.tar.bz2) just do in its directory:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make install
```

This is the usually working setup for ubuntu. And then

```
mono --version
```

to confirm that it actually worked.